# where is my xfburn coredump

Tags: 20.04, xubuntu, segmentation-fault

I'm trying to use xfburn in xubuntu-20.04.3, and it fails on several of my hosts.  I'd like
to submit a bug, but there's a problem.  It ends with a message about SIGSEGV and "core dumped" but I don't see a core dump anywhere.

Am I looking in the wrong place or did it not really happen?

Running "strace xfburn -i" as root, it ends with

> --- SIGSEGV {si_signo=SIGSEGV, si_code=SEGV_MAPERR, si_addr=NULL} ---
> +++ killed by SIGSEGV (core dumped) +++
> Segmentation fault (core dumped)
> root@camelot-b:~#

Sorry if the above is all run together -- I can't seem to make blockquotes work right.

Comment: Read https://askubuntu.com/help/formatting

Answer (score 0):

Read `man ulimit`. You must enable coredumps for your process via

```
ulimit -c unlimited
```

Coredumps are, by default, disabled. This choice was made long ago to avoid novice confusion, and, to avoid filling the tiny disks of the times with random `SEGV` victims.

Answer (score 0):

From my reading of `man xfburn`, I don't think you need to be running `xfburn` as `root`. It's unnecessary,  and running anything as `root` is dangerous, enabling more powerful mistakes.

Many device access problems can be resolved through group membership changes.

Assuming a device name of `/dev/cdrom`,  do.

```
ls -l /dev/cdrom
```

Specifically, if `ls -l`  shows that the group permissions (the second "`rwx`" triplet) is "`rw`" (e.g."`-rw-rw----`"), then, adding oneself to the group that owns the device will grant `rw` access.

Here's how:

```
device="/dev/cdrom"
sudo adduser $USER $(stat -c "%G" $device)
```

This allows you membership in the group that can `rw` the device, **but there is one more step.**

To make all your processes members of the new group, logout and login. Group memberships are set up at `login` time.

To create a single process in the new group (for testing, prior to logout/login):

```
newgrp $(stat -c "%G" $device)
```

or, just type the group name. See `man newgrp`.